# Unreliable consumer with Strimzi Kafka Bridge

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, strimzi

I have a Kafka cluster running in Kubernetes with Strimzi. To communicate with Kafka in HTTP I use the Strimzi [Kafka Bridge](https://strimzi.io/docs/bridge/latest/).
The Producer site works fine using the [POST](https://strimzi.io/docs/bridge/latest/#proc-producing-messages-from-bridge-topics-partitions-bridge) request.
However, I am having problems getting the consumer to run reliably. Whether the consumer receives the messages from the bridge seems to be arbitrary. Often several messages have to be produced first before the bridge returns messages to the consumer. But then all messages together (bulk). I don't want to wait until a larger number of messages has accumulated.
In the documentation they point out that this [behavior](https://strimzi.io/docs/bridge/latest/#proc-bridge-retrieving-latest-messages-from-consumer-bridge) can occur.

I am interested if I can disable this behavior in any way. For example, is there a configuration in Kafka that sets the maximum bulk size?

If you have an idea or need any further information please let me know.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Kafka producers themselves batch records rather than send one-by-one. I haven't used this Strimzi Bridge, but is there a way you can override the internal Kafka producer's `batch.size` or `linger.ms` settings?

Comment: It is possible to set these configurations in the kafka operator but according to the documentation the default of linger.ms is 0. In my understanding this means messages should be instantly consumable. 
https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/configuring.html#optimizing_throughput_and_latency

Comment: That page seems to just discuss general client properties for your code, not necessarily the bridge